# Ajax call is getting a 200 but I'm not inserting a record after function call

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, laravel

This is a bit of a mystery but I think I've narrowed down part of the issue.

Basically, I have a form and when I hit submit I'm making an ajax post that hits my route then controller and this calls a function elsewhere that does an insert (via a procedure in DB2, but basically a straight insert)

My Ajax returns a 200 ok message and shows the form data in the dev tools, so that part is ok. The goal is to take the form values along with the values that I've hard coded in the controller, and pass them to the function which prepares the statement and executes.

I think the issue is the fact that everything coming from the form is a string but my function is expecting `int` and `string` plus the procedure will only insert successfully if the right data type is used. I think the issue is in the form data because if I do a rough hard code and call the function manually in a test file like this, it inserts:

```
$id = 123;
$name1 = 'Test Name';
$number1 = 112;
$name1 = '2nd Test Name';
$number2 = 584;
$number3 = 88;
$name3 = 'Name Blue';
$category = 'Fruit';
$comment = 'Testing the comments';
$date1 = '2018-09-18';
$date2 = '2018-09-19';
```

So basically, I need to still pass my form data, and take that as well as the other values from the controller, make sure strings pass as strings and INT passes as int, then execute the function. I've got to be missing something pretty simple here but I'm 100% lost right now.

Any help is much appreciated

Route.php

```
Route::post('insertPList', 'Controller@insertPList');
```

controller.php

```
public function insertPList(Request $request)
{

        $id = 123;
        $name1 = $request->name1;
        $number1 = $request->number1;
        $name2 = $request->name2;
        $number2 = $request->number2;
        $number3 = $request->number3;
        $name3 = $request->name3;
        $category = 'Fruit';
        $comment = $request->comment;
        $date1 = '2018-09-10';
        $date2 = '2018-09-11';

        $service = new service();
        $service->insertListRecord($id, $name1, $number1,$name2, $number2, $number3, $name3, $category, $comment, $date1, $date2);

}
```

Service.php

```
public function insertListRecord(int $id, string $name1, int $number1, string $name2, int $number2, int $number3, string $name3, string $category, string $comment, string $date1, string $date2)
{
    $link = Iseries::conn();
    $sql = "CALL INSERT_LIST(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $prep = odbc_prepare($link, $sql);
    $exec = odbc_execute($prep, array($id, $name1, $number1, $name2, $number2, $number3, $name3, $category, $comment, $date1, $date2));


    if (odbc_error())
     {
           echo odbc_errormsg($link);
     }
}
```

blade.php

```
    $("#save").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var name1 = $("input[name=name1]").val();
    var number1 = $("input[name=number1]").val();
    var name2 = $("input[name=name2]").val();
    var number2 = $("input[name=number2]").val();
    var number3 = $("input[name=number3]").val();
    var name3 = $("input[name=name3]").val();
    var comment = $("textarea[name=comment]").val();

    $.ajax({
        url:'URL',
        data:{
            name1:name1,
            number1:number1,
            name2:name2,
            number2:number2,
            number3:number3,
            name3:name3,
            comment:comment
        },
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        type:"POST",
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
             alert('Exception:', exception);
         }
    });

});
```

Comment: All HTTP request parameters submitted in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format are strings

Comment: Primitive type hints only work from PHP 7. What version are you using? You could always just cast the variables when you assign them, eg `$number1 = (int) $request->number1;`

Comment: I'm using 7.0.2 I believe. And I know that the parameters are passed as strings, but that's why I'm wondering how I need to pass them properly after the ajax call

Comment: You haven't explained how your code is _not_ working. Are you getting any errors? If you pass a `string` to an `int` type-hinted argument, PHP 7 should throw a [`TypeError`](http://php.net/manual/class.typeerror.php) exception. Numeric strings should be type-converted without issue though

Comment: Note that `odbc_execute()` binds everything as a string anyway so I really don't think this is your issue.

Comment: That's still where I'm confused, because the AJAX call succeeds, and if I put an ```exit()``` under my code in the services, it prints my exit string so it shows that it's making it that far.

Comment: I'm getting no errors: None in the console, none in the network section of the dev tools, none in my laravel logs. I'm getting nothing. My ajax gives me a 200 response, and My record is not inserting. Then If I do a manual insert via a crude script on my local machine, it works

Comment: Believe me, if I had errors I would post them. But that's what I was trying to explain about the ```exit()``` statement, if it's making it all the way through to that, then it's not erroring out

Comment: _"and My record is not inserting"_ <- right, thank you. Are you looking at the correct database? Have you perhaps turned off [autocommit](http://php.net/manual/function.odbc-autocommit.php) in your app?

Comment: Yes it's the right database, and no autocommit is not off. I literally copied/pasted the script from my service function into a local script, ran it with hard coded values and it inserted

Comment: Did you literally copy/paste the ODBC connection part and anything else that might make a change to `$link`? You say you copied it to a **local** script? Assuming the app is hosted somewhere else, are you absolutely sure you're looking at the same DB? Are both scripts connecting to the same DB? Keep in mind, `localhost` means the host executing the script (sorry if this is obvious to you, it's not always the case and I'm not meaning to sound like a jerk).

Comment: No you're not, and I understand how that would usually be the case. Sorry for any confusion, but locally just means a test repo on my machine but using the same development server. All settings the same, so $link is set to the same connection and everything. It's fairly simplified in that regard, I don't have to change any of that for local testing luckily

Comment: Thank you for your help though, I'll just keep trying to debug

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation, if the issue you are having is a type format issue (string, integer, boolean) and you are using the laravel framework then add some thing like this to your model.

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    'number1' => 'integer',
    'name1' => 'string',
    'column name' => 'expected or required format of data',
];
```

Hopefully this should cast the data to your required format before inserting to data base. [See also](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators)